# Как организовать базу данных Laravel 5.8?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

друзья.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с такой проблемой.

Есть сайт по генерации документов. В БД присутствует таблица **documents**. В ней описан сам документ, который нужно сгенерировать.

К этой таблице привязана таблица **form_elements**  отношением *"многие ко многим"*. В этой таблице находятся составные элементы формы, которые выводятся для конкретного документа.

Работает все это, как вы уже поняли, следующим образом: выбирается документ, для него подтягиваются элементы формы и, собственно, формируется сама форма. 

Так вот, уязвимая точка этой схемы такова, что элементы формы подтягиваются в том порядке, в каком они находятся в таблице-посреднике (например, сначала ФИО, потом адрес...).

А что делать, если нужно поменять порядок вывода этих элементов в админке?

При этом, как вы поняли, такой порядок индивидуален для каждого документа.

Что сделал я.
Я создал таблицу **order** c 3-мя колонками **doc_id** (номер документа), **form_element_id** (номер элемента формы), **order** (порядок, в котором он должен быть в конечной форме).

Таблицу **documents** я связал с **order** отношением "1 ко многим".

Таким образом я получаю элементы формы в нужном мне порядке.

Но, сказать по правде, это какой-то костыль. Да и такую таблицу очень неудобно обслуживать.

Может кто-то подскажет как сделать все более красиво и элегантно?

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас **form_elements** и **documents** связаны как "многие ко многим", то я так полагаю, таблица **order** и есть 3-я связующая таблица данного отношения. Следуя из такой логики, колонка order в данной таблице - хороший вариант и он не является костыльным.

Не вижу проблем в обслуживании данной схемы - обычные запросы с join-ами и только)